# How to get a selector of a class method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, selector, objective-c-runtime

I have the next code where I am getting a pointer to instance method:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface TestClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation TestClass
- (void)someMethod { // This is instance method, it's okay
  NSLog(@"Hello from some method!");
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  typedef void (*MethodWithoutParams)();
  MethodWithoutParams someMethodImplementation = 
class_getMethodImplementation([TestClass class], @selector(someMethod));
  someMethodImplementation();
  return 0;
}
```

It works pretty good. But if I'd like to get a pointer to class method, it doesn't work:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface TestClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation TestClass
+ (void)someMethod { // This is class method, it doesn't work
  NSLog(@"Hello from some method!");
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  typedef void (*MethodWithoutParams)();
  MethodWithoutParams someMethodImplementation = 
class_getMethodImplementation([TestClass class], @selector(someMethod));
  someMethodImplementation();
  return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work because it can not look up the method implementation.

I am sure it **must** work, because it works if I am getting the implementation in such way:

```
MethodWithoutParams someMethodImplementation = 
[TestClass methodForSelector:@selector(someMethod)];
```

So I looked into NSObject implementation and see the next code:

```
+ (IMP)methodForSelector:(SEL)sel {
    if (!sel) [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:sel];
    return object_getMethodImplementation((id)self, sel);
}

- (IMP)methodForSelector:(SEL)sel {
    if (!sel) [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:sel];
    return object_getMethodImplementation(self, sel);
}
```

Also `object_getMethodImplementation()` function [has](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-646/runtime/objc-class.mm) the next implementation:

```
IMP object_getMethodImplementation(id obj, SEL name)
{
    Class cls = (obj ? obj->getIsa() : nil);
    return class_getMethodImplementation(cls, name);
}
```

So the implementation is same for both class method lookup and instance method lookup.

But it doesn't work and I have no idea why. I guess that any type of methods (both class and instance) gonna be located in the dispatch table, and I can get the pointer to any of this methods. But as you see I can't do it.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Wain I just want to know how the Objective-C Runtime works. Unfortunately official documentation does not describe this question so deep.

Comment: They are not the same implementation. `self` in an instance method and `self` in a class method are different. So it calls `object_getMethodImplementation` with different `self`s.

Comment: @mostruash you're right, but it works via `[TestClass methodForSelector:@selector(someMethod)];` as I described.

Comment: Note that it's an entirely different function being called: `object_getMethodImplementation` is not the same as `class_getMethodImplementation`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to query the class's metaclass. A class method is an instance method on its metaclass.

```
Class meta = objc_getMetaClass("TestClass");
SEL sel = @selector(someMethod);
typedef void (*MyMethodImplementation)(Class, SEL);
MyMethodImplementation someMethodImplementation = (MyMethodImplementation)class_getMethodImplementation(meta, sel);
someMethodImplementation([TestClass class], sel);
```

Note, a method (instance or class) is never "without parameters". It must always be called with at least the receiver (instance or class) and the selector.

Comment: Thank you so much for help! Yes I know that I must pass at least two this parameters to method. I've just simplified the code for testing.

Comment: or equivalently, `Class meta = object_getClass([TestClass class]);` to show that the process is really exactly the same with instance methods

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no idea about Objective-C runtime. But here is my rant:

**object_getMethodImplementation for class methods:**

```
// returns a class method implementation, can't find instance methods
class_getMethodImplementation([TestClass class]->getIsa(),
                              @selector(classMethod));
```

which is equivalent to

```
class_getMethodImplementation(objc_getMetaClass("TestClass"),
                              @selector(classMethod));
```

**object_getMethodImplementation for instance methods:**

```
// returns an instance method implementation, can't find class methods
class_getMethodImplementation((<TestClass instance>)->getIsa(),
                              @selector(someMethod));
```

which is equivalent to:

```
class_getMethodImplementation([TestClass class], 
                              @selector(someMethod))
```

---

So it seems that `<TestClass instance>->getIsa()` returns a pointer that is equal to what `[TestClass class]` returns. And I guess now you know what's the difference between a `self` in a class method and a `self` in an instance method.

So you should use meta class as @KenThomases suggests.